# sum of integers of two exponents equal

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

For what values of n, such that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+,$ does the sum of digits $(214)^n$ and $(2014)^n$ equal?

So I found $1$, which is fairly obvious, there are supposed to be more?

Comment: also for $n=0$..

Comment: N is supposed to be a positive integer

Comment: That question looks contesty. Where is it from?

Comment: Friend gave to me, actually yeah it does seem contesty. Google gives me nothing though. I guess i could add a tag

Comment: Also $n=2$.  (Meaningless filler in parentheses.)

Comment: 0, 1, and 2 are the only solutions for $0 \le n \le 2000$

Comment: Since you know it is a finite set of solutions. Couldn't we try to prove that after a set value for $n$ the sums will reach a point of divergence. Therefore we only need to focus on the points $m\le n$? Then it would just be a simple computational proof for the rest of it.